# EXTENDED_ARG in Python Bytecide

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering, bytecode

I have a Python bytecode file and i don't have the original .py file. I try to run it. However, it raises an error `[1]    5811 segmentation fault  python flag5.pyc`. I know that if i remove all the `EXTENDED_ARG` below, it will be a list looks like this: `a = [1,12,9,217,376,...,1,12]` However, there are many`EXTENDED_ARG`in the bytecode and they are in the middle of the `LOAD_CONST` instructions.
Therefore,(1) what python code can it be?
 (2) How to calculate `BUILD_LIST` size to avoid segmentation fault?

```
 LOAD_CONST           (1)
 LOAD_CONST           (12)
 EXTENDED_ARG         1 (256)
 LOAD_CONST           (9)
 LOAD_CONST           (217)
 LOAD_CONST           (376)
 EXTENDED_ARG         1 (256)
 ...
 LOAD_CONST           (1)
 LOAD_CONST           (12)
 EXTENDED_ARG         9 (2304)
 EXTENDED_ARG         2467 (631552)
 BUILD_LIST           631690
```

I'm using Python3.8.0.

Comment: What did you do to get the disassembly output you posted? (Yes, this is relevant.)

Comment: Also, where did this bytecode file come from, and how did it come to be corrupted? If we know that, we have a better chance of being able to reverse it, or at least salvage more of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use xdis and xasm with command ``` pydisasm --asm``` to get disassembly output.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG:

> `EXTENDED_ARG(ext)`
>
> Prefixes any opcode which has an argument too big to fit into the default one byte. `ext` holds an additional byte which act as higher bits in the argument. For each opcode, at most three prefixal `EXTENDED_ARG` are allowed, forming an argument from two-byte to four-byte.